# SELECTING repetitive rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have saved all users' IPs in MYSQL. How can I SELECT users who registered with the same IP twice or more?

I know DISTINCT function in MySQL is for selecting unique rows, what about my situation? Are the any functions or I have just to run loop?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say users do you mean *same* users from *same* IP, or simply IPs for which there are several records?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it is possible to have unique users with the same IP address. Especially over time.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT count(*) cnt, name
FROM `users`
GROUP BY ip
HAVING cnt >1
```

Comment: Pending clarification by OP one of us is wrong :D Also a comment: due to dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html the selection of `name` is nondeterministic, which for me is useless... here you might actually do `group_concat(name)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ip FROM table GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(users)>1
```

Comment: 2 things: COUNT(2) >= 2 *AND* there must be a group by there otherwise single random row is returned - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I had posted and I guess I updated my answer  prior to seeing your comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Never ever `COUNT` something that is not `*` unless you know exactly what you are doing. If have columns which aren't `NOT NULL` `COUNT`s on them can yield different and much slower results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userid, ip
FROM users
GROUP BY userid, ip
HAVING COUNT(userid) > 1;
```